# VC2013 Express unresolved link PlaySound

Tags: unsatisfiedlinkerror, playsound, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to port an application from VC6 to VC2013 express and I've solved the compiler issues but linker cant find __imp__PlaySoundA (LNK2019). My code calls PlaySound and I have the windows.h and mmsystem.h include files (otherwise I'd get a compiler error). The project configuration uses the $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86) directory in the Library Directories and I can see winmm.dll in the system32 folder so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found I need to add a #pragma comment. Problem resolved.